# How to move an existing installation of Cytoscape + all installed apps

Tags: cytoscape

I would like to move a previous installation of Cytoscape from an old machine. Mainly, I need to use ClusterONE, which was removed from the Cytoscape app store at the start of this year. I've tried copying the whole c:/program_files as well as the C:/users/.../CytoscapeConfiguration folder to a new machine but ClusterONE still doesn't show. Are there any other folders that I need to also copy over? Better yet, is there any way to install a previously removed app such as ClusterONE?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ClusterOne, but as far as I know, $user/CytoscapeConfiguration is where everything, including apps and app configuration information, should go.  Do you get any errors when you start Cytoscape?

-- scooter

Comment: nope, no errors. however, the apps menu doesn't show clusterone to be installed at all. so i am thinking it might be a registry setting i might need to tweak? but im not enritrely sure